# connecting and sending data to webpage vc++

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I am modifing the code for a dll to read telemetry from ets2 ([located here](http://download.eurotrucksimulator2.com/scs_sdk_1_2.zip))

What I want to do is to send the data to a server using either a POST or GET request to my server so I can log it when people have installed the api. However, I am having trouble getting this working.

So far all I have changed in the file is included these:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Wininet.h>
#include <tchar.h>
```

and added this code where it would normally write the file:

```
log_print(";%f;%f;%f", telemetry.heading, telemetry.pitch, telemetry.roll);
        std::wstring url = L"http://localhost/get.php?value=value";

        HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen(L"Test", 0, NULL, NULL, 0);
        HINTERNET hOpenUrl = InternetOpenUrl(hSession, url.c_str(), NULL, 0, 1, 1);

        InternetCloseHandle(hOpenUrl);
        InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
```

However, I am getting these errors when I add this code and I do not understand why:

```
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__InternetOpenW@20 referenced in function "void __stdcall telemetry_frame_end(unsigned int,void const * const,void * const)" (?telemetry_frame_end@@YGXIQBXQAX@Z)    C:\Users\marcushann\Downloads\scs_sdk_1_2\examples\telemetry\telemetry.obj  telemetry


Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__InternetCloseHandle@4 referenced in function "void __stdcall telemetry_frame_end(unsigned int,void const * const,void * const)" (?telemetry_frame_end@@YGXIQBXQAX@Z)   C:\Users\marcushann\Downloads\scs_sdk_1_2\examples\telemetry\telemetry.obj  telemetry


Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__InternetOpenUrlW@24 referenced in function "void __stdcall telemetry_frame_end(unsigned int,void const * const,void * const)" (?telemetry_frame_end@@YGXIQBXQAX@Z) C:\Users\marcushann\Downloads\scs_sdk_1_2\examples\telemetry\telemetry.obj  telemetry


Error   6   error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals   C:\Users\marcushann\Downloads\scs_sdk_1_2\examples\telemetry\Debug\telemetry.dll    1   1   telemetry
```

Please could you give me some insight into these errors and how to fix them.

Thanks,
Marcus

Comment: Link with `Wininet.lib`. Project > Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies. Next time, read the documentation for the API functions you use, down to and including "Requirements" section at the bottom. It tells you which header to include, and which library to link.

Comment: ah, thanks, I had read down which is how I knew to include wininet.h I am new to vc++ and didn't realise you had to do that. sorry!

Comment: Maybe a little offtopic, but you may also try another open source ETS2 telemetry solution that already provide REST API: https://github.com/Funbit/ets2-telemetry-server

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your comment, we have actually based our updated client on your source (of course we have added full credit and are releasing under mit and including your license) as it is not practical for us to use a web api on the client end so I have turned it into a library and am using it in our projects.